# Technical advantages of transferring domain name

Tags: dns, domain-name

I have a website hosted in Switzerland and the domain registrar is in the US.
If I requested a transfer of the domain from the US to the registrar in Switzerland, what technical advantage would that give me, if any? 
Are there any significant things to pay attention to apart from little things (such as price)?

If not I would leave it in the US then and just change dns records...

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link between domain name and hosting (IP address) is simple an ip address corresponds to a name. But for a name to be valid and some people to have jobs there are additional steps:

Root name servers -> Authority name servers slave nemeservers

The registrars provide a list of authoritative name servers coupled with names to the root servers (this is called glue). Usually the person owning a domain can change the authoritative name servers via some panel.

That being said the only technical advantages i can think of are:

- Price for the registration (per year)
- Willingness of the registrar to shutdown a domain under pressure on or request

  - the registrar can change the Name servers and point the domain wherever he wants and can block you from changing this which effectively shuts down the domain.

Please also remember that in the end the registrars (the real ones also called NIC's) are not so much and usually can be found by simply typing .ext e.g. nic.com, nic.org

The other companies selling domains are just resellers and using any of them should be guided mostly by features they offer and price (e.g. how usable is their panel, how fast they respond to tickets, etc.)